# Add break after every set of three images jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm generating images dynamically and willing to add break after every set of three images, so every set of three images will be new line:

```
<img class="test">
<img class="test">
<img class="test">
<img class="test">
<img class="test">
```

Expected result:

```
<img class="test">
<img class="test">
<img class="test">
<br>
<img class="test">
<img class="test">
<img class="test">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) and [`.after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after/):

```js
$(function () {
  $(".test:nth-child(3n)").after("<br />");
});
```

```css
.test {border: 1px solid #999; width: 25px; height: 25px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <img class="test" />
  <img class="test" />
  <img class="test" />
  <img class="test" />
  <img class="test" />
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be just 3n rather?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Checked it bro. `3n` just gives ... Wait. I guess it is because of the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

simply this

```
$('.test:nth-child(3n)').after('<br>')
```

use the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) to select 3rd element

Comment: Doesn't work... Kindly check your answer before posting.

Comment: @PraveenKumar sorry forgot to add n-th child in a hurry.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it should work as per the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: @gurvinder372 Works perfectly.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Yes, bro... Stack Snippets are the real culprits. LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Lol, I have almost never used snacksnippets. It is neither easy to use nor intuitive. Rely on jsfiddle heavily :)

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Snippet is confused. So we sent it to home. `:P`